# pip のインストール後、pip3 コマンドは使えるが pip コマンドが見つからない

Tags: python, macos, pip

[Installation — pip 20.1.1 documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

上記サイトの手順を参考に、下記のコマンドを順に実行したところ `pip3` コマンドは使えるようになりましたが、`pip` コマンドが見つかりません。

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

`pip3`コマンドのまま使ってもいいのですが、書籍やネットの各種情報が `pip` コマンドを使っているのでコピペして実行するとき手間です。

エイリアス等作ってコマンド入力を楽にしてしまってもいいのですが、`pip`コマンドが入らなかったのが気になります。今後Pythonコミュニティ（？）で`pip3`のみを使っていくというような決まり等なにか理由あるのでしょうか？

環境: mac os mojave 10.14.6

[背景]
Anacondaを入れたところ、Python3が入ったようですが（おそらく同時にPython2も入った?）、pipが入らなかったようなので、自力で入れました。

ターミナルで `python --version`と打つと`Python 2.7.10`です。
これは古いなあと思って、`python3 --version`を打ってみたところ`Python 3.7.7`でした。
なので、Python自体の実行は `python`ではなくて`python3`で実行しています（これも手間ですね）

`get-pip.py`の実行はAnacondaを入れた後にpipがないことに気づき、実行したのですが、pythonとそのまま打つとPython2が動くことに気づいていなかったので、`get-pip.py`はPython2で実行されたはずです。

Anaconda自体は `Anaconda3-2020.02-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg` で入れました。

追記
[conda と pip でのパッケージ管理について - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ynakayama/items/29efebeb38604d10acef)
こんな記事を見つけました。

> さて、よくある話が conda と pip を併用すると「壊れる」という言説。なにをもって壊れると主張しているのかよくわかりませんが、そもそも同じパッケージに対し conda で入れたり pip で入れたりしている状況が異常なわけです。

なるほど。`conda` というコマンドがあるようですね。 私の見た参考資料には Anacondaを入れたあとに pip を実行とあったのでpipを実行したのですが... Python初学者には、このあたりのエコシステムがわからないのでツライですなあ...

Comment: 使っているOSの種類と版数が影響するかもしれないので追記してみてください。あとPython自身の版数は2系と3系が共存しているのでしょうか？

Comment: @kunif 追記しました

Comment: その辺の内容だと私には知識経験が無いので答えてくれる人を待ちましょう。

Answer (score 1):

AnacondaのインストールだけでPython2.X系とPython3.X系が同時にインストールされることはあり得ないと思います。
おそらく以前にPython2.X系の環境がインストールされており、その後Anaconda(Python3.X系)をインストールなさったのではと推測しています。

たしか、Anaconda(Python2.X系)のインストール後にAnaconda(Python3.X系)をインストールするとpipの名称が被るので、先にインストールされていた2.X系は「pip」で、3.X系は「pip3」という名前でパッケージの実行ファイルが保存されるはずです。