# python3.8.5 にはpipが一緒にインストールされない？

Tags: python, python3

こんにちは。先ほど、python3.8.5をインストールしたものです。その後、bashに`pip`と入力しても

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

と出ます。
今までは3.7.6を使っていたのですが、その時は

```
Usage: pip ...
```

と出てきました。最近のバージョンには全てpipが付いていると、独学プログラマーという本に書いてあったので困惑しています。
ちなみに3.8.5のインストールは公式サイトの  Download Python3.8.5 というボタンから行ないました。

Comment: OSはWindowsでしょうか？ 質問文に明記してください。またWindowsであればbashは付属していないので、何らかの方法でインストールしているはずです。どのようなbashなのかにも依存します。ちなみにコマンドプロンプトからはpipを実行できますか？

Comment: この記事が参考になるかも。[pip or pip3 to install packages for Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40832533/9014308)

Comment: 参考までにですが、私も別の方法でやって入らなかったので、自力でいれました。気になったので質問したものが次の質問です。

[python - pip のインストール後、pip3 コマンドは使えるが pip コマンドが見つからない - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/68691/pip-%e3%81%ae%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e5%be%8c-pip3-%e3%82%b3%e3%83%9e%e3%83%b3%e3%83%89%e3%81%af%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b%e3%81%8c-pip-%e3%82%b3%e3%83%9e%e3%83%b3%e3%83%89%e3%81%8c%e8%a6%8b%e3%81%a4%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)

Comment: Python.orgからのダウンロード・インストールだと関係ないかもしれませんが、こんな記事があるようです。[Homebrew から Python が消えた・・・](https://qiita.com/shotakaha/items/61cb226959917640e7c0)